# Installed windows 10 on a separate HD and installed a GPU. Now Ubuntu doesn't work

Tags: dual-boot, gpu-driver

I just bought another hard drive and installed windows 10 on it today. I was hoping to be able to choose between drives at boot. As soon as I installed windows 10 I also installed a GPU, as soon as I tried to boot Ubuntu I got nothing at all. I removed the Windows HD, still nothing. Cleared the CMOS, got a purple screen like it was starting to go, then it went black and said no input. I removed the GPU, cleared the CMOS, got Ubuntu to load, but the internet wouldn't work? Any ideas how I can fix this and get the GPU to work with Ubuntu? It's a MSI Radeon R7 370.

I tried turning fast boot off on windows 10 and now all I'm getting from the hard drive with Ubnutu is "Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key."

Comment: Okay, I've removed the HD that had windows 10 installed on it. And the GPU. Got Ubuntu to boot consistently and correctly by itself. However, with the GPU installed it will display a purple screen, like its about to boot, then my monitor says no input detected from both the GPU and the motherboard? Any ideas on this? I just want to be able to play some games on this computer, occasionally. I don't mind disconnecting the Ubuntu HD and connecting the Windows HD every time, because it wont be often. Is it possible to do that or will I still have issues from windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Ubuntu 14'04 and Windows 10  using two hard drives. Isolate the drives when loading each hard drive. To select either program use the bios program when you boot up.